# How to draw the below structure "Append a Rectangle Tag" before the start and end for each section

Tags: c#, loops

[image]How to Append the Rectangle xml tag for every section in the below data set.

I am having a dataset myDs  with following rows.Please read 3rd column SubSubSection
(Parent-->child-->Child)

I need to draw the below structure and Append a Rectange before the start and end for each section.

From the  dataset. How can i do that with the c# code.

I am dynamically generated SSRS Report and constructing the SSRS tags using the .net C# .
[image]
Please help !!!
Vineet

Comment: Any comments on this or Need any other information ???